# Upper bounding the chromatic number of a graph minor

Tags: graph-theory, graph-minors

Let $H$ be a minor of $G$. By letting $G$ be an even cycle, we see that $\chi(H) \leq \chi(G)$ does not hold. Is there some other upper bound that would hold, for instance is $\chi(H) \leq \chi(G) + c$ true, where $c$ is some constant?

I really only care about edge contractions, but if a good bound can be obtained for a minor (i.e., when allowing for edge and vertex deletion too) that's also fine.

The question [Can contracting an edge increase the chromatic number by more than one?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1470018/660787) says that if we just contract *a single* edge, we indeed have that $c = 1$. But what if an arbitrary sequence of contractions is allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get a bound of the form $\chi(G) + c$ (although I'm sure other, weaker bounds do exist).

There are lots of ways to see this, but probably the easiest is by the following construction.
Let $H$ be the complete graph $K_n$. Make a graph $G$ from $H$ by replacing each edge with a path of length $2$. This new graph $G$ is bipartite, and hence has $\chi(G) = 2$ (to see this, make all the *old* $K_n$ vertices red, and all the *new* vertices in the middle of the `edges' blue).

Now we have that $H$ is a minor of $G$ (just contract all the paths of length $2$ back into edges), but $\chi(H) - \chi(G) = n-2$, which we can make as large as we like by picking a bigger $n$.

Of course, if your sequence of contractions has only $k$ contractions, then $\chi(H) \leq \chi(G) + k$.

Comment: By the way, if you (or anyone else) happen(s) to know of any other weaker bounds, I'd be curious to learn more.

Comment: @DanTony I don't know any myself, but I think the place to look for this sort of thing is the work on "Hadwiger's Conjecture". The conjecture says that if $\chi(G) = n$, then $G$ has $K_n$ as a minor. If the conjecture is true, then the largest chromatic number of *any* minor of $G$ would always be the largest $n$ such that $G$ had $K_n$ as a minor.